# jQuery Form Validate() : How to setup default messages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, jquery-validate

Until now, I've used [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) with previously defined fields. Now I'm working with a dynamic form. Fields have their validation needs mapped by its classes (e.g. " required "), but I don't see how to customize the messages jQuery validate throws.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can add your messages like so.

```
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        required: "your msg",
        email: "your email msg",
        digits: "your digits msg"
    });
```

See [setDefaults](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults)

Answer (score 8):

```
$.validator.messages.required = "My new, default required message!";
```

Answer (score 1):

[setDefaults](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults)